# Product Matrix For Products

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product

I sell clothes on my store, I am looking for a way to be able to select multiple options.

For example my client decides to buy a T-Shirt. I would like to display the T-Shirt with the options Red, Green, Blue and then Small Large X-Large. So the client can purchase the product without having to add the products one by one. The client can then just input how many of each and then add to cart.

Anybody know of a module that could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is basic Magento Configurable products behaviour, please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product.